# Loading files in Android

Tags: android, file-io

I have a class (just a regular class) that holds lists that my app uses. These lists are refreshed from the web and stored locally as an XML file. The code to get a list would look like this:

```
private static List<String> list1;
public static List<String> getList1() {
    if (list1 == null) {

        //load it
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            //do stuff with the file here...
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //if the file is missing load it from the web
        }

    }

    return list1;
}
```

so this method would return the list object, if it's not present it would load it from the local file, if that is not present it would load it from the web. But the problem i have is that the `openFileInput()` doesnt resolve in my class since it's just a normal class and it would need to be called from a Context. What is the best way to do this? Use a Context as an argument for `getList1()`? But that cant be done everywhere since it's called in all sorts of classes...

Comment: Use the `Application` context.  Files are associated with the app, not an `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a new class `App`:

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static Context context;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

and by adding `android:name="path.to.App"` the the Android manifest. This way you'll always have a global context and can use it from everywhere.